# Make checkboxes and row click in Table component behave differently in Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using a Material-UI Table component in my React web application, but I can't seem to figure out how to prevent the entire row from being selected when a user clicks somewhere on a table row. I only want the row selected if the user checks the checkbox. If the user clicks anywhere else, I want to show additional details on the row of data.

For additional context, my Table basically functions as a mailbox. When users click the row (a message), it should open a new page with further details, but when users check the checkbox next to the message in the table, the user should be able to flag is important, etc.

How would I go about doing this? Should I be using `onCellClick` and not use `onRowSelection`?

Answer (score 2):

You can work around this behavior by stopping the event propagation in each `<TableRowColumn>`. In order to do this just add a `<div>` with an `onClick` handler to each `<TableRowColumn>`. Something like this

`<TableRowColumn>
    <div onClick={(e) => {e.stopPropagation()}}>Column 1</div>
 </TableRowColumn>`

Just make sure you add this to every `<TableRowColumn>`